# How to split object by plane via script

Tags: python, scripting

I have a single *complex* 3D object. I would like to cut this object at regular intervals along the x-axis into separate objects. This is because I want to apply a separate particle system to each piece, as I need a higher resolution than I would get by applying 250 to the whole object.

I have written code for applying the particle system to a single object, although I will need to write a for loop that handles each piece to make sure that unnecessary objects are deleted (I only want to keep the particles).

Note that using something like "separate by loose parts" results in hundreds of little loose objects and is not at all helpful to me.

What is the right method/function for scripting this procedure?

To illustrate what I want:

> input: [---]
>
> output: [-][-][-]

And I would not be interested in moving anything at all, I just need the pieces to be defined as separate objects so I can apply the particle system to each.

Comment: Just for clarification can the desired effect be achieved by creating a cube mesh around part of your complex object then selecting your object as active(both the cube & your object must be selected) then using the btool slice command (<shift><ctrl><numpad / >) ? or are you trying to create a single slice plane that will intersect and separate multiple objects at once?

Comment: I am starting off with a single coherent object so it is possible that the method you are suggesting could work. I would need to be able to iterate to perform as many cuts as needed. I can't seem to get anything to happen with the keyboard shortcut you suggested (v2.79) however.

Comment: Alex, my apologies you will need to have the addon Bool Tools enabled. File>user preferences>addons>(object category) Bool Tool

Comment: @Ratt thanks. Is there a way to seal off the edges where the mesh is cut? The cut is leaving hollows which completely throws off my particle system.